# laravel implode maped collection with link (a tag)

Tags: php, html, laravel-8

i use laravel 8 method for map key and join them with implode
it's work fine but i want joined value with link

my code :

```
{{$item->artists->map(function ($artist, $key) {
  return $artist->title ;
})->implode('meta_value', ' , ')}}
```

it return somthing like : `artist-1 , artist-2`

but i want somthing like : `<a href="artist-1">artist-1</a> , <a href="artist-2">artist-2</a>`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the full string within the map like so:

```
{!!$item->artists->map(function ($artist, $key) {
  return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $artist->title['meta_value'], $artist->title['meta_value']);
})->join(' , ')!!}
```

Comment: it's return as string not html tags

Comment: Try my new edit, the `{{ }}` tags escape HTML so I switch to `{!! !!}` instead